# how to link QR code to a cat photo (REACT)

Tags: reactjs, ajax, webapi

here I have an ajax request that gets the photo of a random cat

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
class RandomCat extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {}
    this.fetchRandomCatImg = this.fetchRandomCatImg.bind(this)
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchRandomCatImg()
  }

  fetchRandomCatImg() {
    fetch("https://aws.random.cat/meow")
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        this.setState({
          error: null,
          ready: true,
          src: data.file
        })
      })
      .catch(error => this.setState({ error }))
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.error) return <p>Oops, something went wrong!</p>
    if (!this.state.ready) return <p>Loading...</p>
    return <img src={this.state.src} className="cat" alt="random cat photo" />
  }
}
export default RandomCat;
```

here we need to make a qr image code that links to the same photo that gets generated from that call 
it means we need to pass data resulted from the cat api to the other ajax call that gets the qr code
I tried doing this but it gave another photo(new one)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
class QR extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {}
    this.fetchQR = this.fetchQR.bind(this)
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchQR()
  }

  fetchQR() {
    fetch("https://qrtag.net/api/qr_12.svg?url=https://aws.random.cat/meow" )
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        this.setState({
          error: null,
          ready: true,
          src: data.file
        })
      })
      .catch(error => this.setState({ error }))
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.error) return <p>Oops, something went wrong!</p>
    if (!this.state.ready) return <p>Loading...</p>
    return <img className="QR"src={this.state.src} alt="qrtag"/>
  }
}
export default QR;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bit different but you can use this package:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/qrcode.react

And then you only need to do one API call. Once the URL of the file is in your state, you display the QR Code like this:

```
<QRCode value={this.state.src} />
```

But if you still want to use the QR code generator API, you need to pass the URL of the cat you just fetched to this component, the value of `data.fetch` (`this.state.src`).

If you pass it `https://aws.random.cat/meow` of course it won't work.

Comment: Ok, it's a requirement to use the api generator.

Comment: You mean I should pass the (this.state.src) of the random cat class to the qr class?

Comment: I actually have trouble passing data from the RandomCat component to the QR component